# is it possible to write async code in setState callback

Tags: reactjs

Can you write async code in the setState callback. I am trying to implement field level validation of form. I want to call the validation method after the onChange method has set the state to the new value.

I got everything to work properly with yup and its validateSync method. The synchronous code works properly. But lately I thought of re-implementing the logic to make the validation code async and use the yup validate (async) method. But after getting it to work and returning the value after validation, when I try to set the state by returning the new values, it doesn't seem to do anything.

the code looks something like this ->

***edit -> setState callback calls validateFormField (sorry I realised, I missed some code when trying to
over simplify it***

```js
this.state = {
  formElements: [{}, {}, {}]    //array of objects having fields name, value, err, etc
}
handleChange(() => {
  this.setState(prevState => {
    //logic for updating the value
    return {formElements: newFormElements}
  }, () => {
    const formElements = this.state.formElements;
    validateFormField(fieldName);
  })
)

validateFormField(fieldName) {
  this.setState(prevState => {
    /*
      validateField -> Async function that has yup.validate which returns null
      in try block
      and throws error in the catch block with the formElements object updated
      with validation values
    */
    return validateField(fieldName)
      .then(() => {
      /* 
        expected behaviour up till this point and since there is nothing
        updated, I return null so as to tell react not to update the state
      */
      return null;
    })
    .catch(newFormElements => {
      /*
        expected behaviour untill this point and since formElements object
        is updated, I return the new object, so as to tell react to update
        the state with the new value
      */
      return {formElements: newFormElements};
     })
   })
 }
```

---

Also I have two sub questions which are related to the above question: 
1> Are there any drawbacks to using async validations? Since the React setState method is also async, it might cause unexpected behaviour, since there might be a race condition. As in the onChange calls the setState for the next value change before the Async code of the previous validation finishes, causing React to show validation error, even if the new value is valid.

2> Are there any drawbacks to using sync validations? The reason I was trying to implement async validation logic even when my sync works perfectly, is because I have heard that Its best practice to use async code whenever possible especially for heavy work like validation. Since the heavy validation could cause the only thread to be occupied and nothing else able to being executed in that event loop.

Comment: Async code in this circumstance doesn't make sense. What is the benefit you are hoping for?

Comment: @AlexMckay As I pointed out in the point 2, I thought it would be better for performance, since it wouldn't block the event loop. Although, I am not completely sure, it did make sense for me to attempt it. Also, I thought, there was a reason that the yup library had async validate function. Anyways, I would hope someone points out that async is not needed and gives a valid reason for it, since I already have a working code for sync validations. And I use debounce, so that I don't call it on every onChange.

Comment: async validation make no sense. Whoever told you that it is best practice to use async is IMO completely wrong. Validation is not heavy-lifting work either. It is a few RegEx expressions at most.

Comment: You should only look to optimize your React app when you notice it is slowing down and you do that with the Profiler. Trying to optimise early by using async validations is such a waste of your time and make no even make your application quicker and is in fact more likely to make your application slower.

Comment: @AlexMckay Agreed for few and simple fields, but regex can be very expensive too in some cases, and for a lot of fields with even date validations, I don't know. Also, the reason I first went with sync validation, was because I wanted it to be kinda blocking since I made sense. But recently I shifted to materail-ui and started using its form elements, and it seemed to me that the blocking code was making my material-ui not be smooth. Since I thought the blocking sync validation was hampering the execution of mui stuff, I tried the async approach to see the difference.

Comment: @AlexMckay Yeah right now, It does seems like a big waste of time, since I have already spend 1 and half day trying to implement the logic. I wanted to ask this before going through with the implementation, but since I know how stackoverflow is, someone would close the question saying its based on opinion and personal preferences, so I thought I would rather see for myself. But I ended up getting stuck anyways. But I would like to know a proper ans in any case, since if someone does ask me about it in my next project, I will have a concrete answer to my using sync validations vs async.

Comment: Your answer should be making form validation async adds developer overhead and is rarely beneficial to the user experience from a performance perspective. The main reason formik provides async validation is because sometimes you might need to check something on a database such as if the username provided is a duplicate. Using async validation as a method of performance improvement is completely over the top. If your validation is blocking use a spinner.

Comment: @AlexMckay Thanks for your suggestion. Really appreciate it. So, I do know where you stand on my sub questions. Do you have an idea about the main question? Is it possible to wrtie async in the setState callback? or make the callback itself async?

Answer (score 0):

This would be how I would do it.

```js
doSomethingSync(state) {
// ...
}
async doSomethingAsync(state) {
// ...
}

handleChange(() => {
  this.setState(prevState => {}, () => {
  doSomethingSync(state)
  doSomethingAsync(state).then().catch()
}
```